# How to display character icon in Mysql 'CASE'?

Tags: mysql, icons, case

I want to display icon character via mysql case. But when I run it, the character is printed as a string. So, how to display icon character in "CASE" mysql?

This is my code :

```
CASE WHEN id_sw=tf.id_sw THEN '' ELSE '&#x26A0;' END) as icon
```

So, when i run this code, so the icon still string. Note: I use vue.js for view so, i can't initialize condition if for icon.

Thankyou

Comment: How are you displaying the query results? `&#x26a0;` is an HTML entity, it needs to be displayed on a web page.

Comment: Yeah, i want to displayed that on webpage. but the webpage print/echo "icon"

Comment: Show the code that creates the web page from the query results.

Comment: Vue.js may be treating the controller response as literal text, not HTML.

Answer (score 0):

The problem (most likely) is that Vue is escaping the string that is returned by your database and it is displayed literally in your browser. This is a good thing, it prevents a lot of javascript attack vectors. It is possible to solve this [on the vue side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46756802/vue-js-auto-convert-html-and-unicode-entities), but I wouldn't really recommend it.

Could you try inserting the character direcly in your query, instead of the HTML entity?

```sql
CASE WHEN id_sw=tf.id_sw THEN '' ELSE '⚠' END) as icon
```

You might have to tweak the encoding of your DB connection/your web page to get the symbol to display correctly, but this would be the optimal solution.

Comment: Sorry just saw your answer.
Yes, your answer is very helpful and solved.